# Spring Rest Template - Queries related to closing of Http Client

Tags: spring, rest

I have created class Rest Client and autowired the Spring RestTemplate having scope singleton.

So any Rest Call to server would be using the same RESTClient and I dont create a new Client for each call rest call.

So i am  re-using the Rest client object .

1: Do i need to create a new Rest Client for each request ?
2: Do i need to  close the httpClient connection after each Rest call ?

Comment: Could you add the relevant code (the `RestTemplate` config and your `RESTClient`)?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Rest Template handles all  the connection closing